# How to make a username mandatory in sign up page in swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I have created a register page using firebase email and password auth. At the moment the user does not have to enter a username to create an account. How do i make it mandatory for them to enter a username?

```
        @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var profileUploader: UIImageView!

  var refD:FIRDatabaseReference?
    var refS: FIRStorageReference?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        refD = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        refS = FIRStorage.storage().reference()
        profileUploader.layer.cornerRadius = 2
        profileUploader.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    @IBAction func registerTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let namec = nameTextField.text
        if let email = emailTextField.text, let pass = passwordTextField.text, let name = namec?.capitalized {
            FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: pass, completion: { (user, error) in
                if user != nil {
                    //user found

                    let interval = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
                    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: interval)
                    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy/HH/mm/SS"
                    // you can change the date format to whatever you wants
                    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
                    print(dateString)




                    self.refD?.child("Users").child((user?.uid)!).setValue(["Email": email, "Name": name, "User Created": dateString])
                    print("User Created And Added To Database", email, name, dateString)
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "registertologin", sender: self)
                }
```

Comment: So, is that you want make validation on username textfield or do setup some firebase rules?

Comment: @jaydeep i dont understand what you mean. i fixed the problem. thanks for help anyways :D

Comment: add this line if let name = (namec?.capitalized.isEmpty)! ? nil:namec { //code } else { var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)}

Comment: This line chnage is this line... if let email = emailTextField.text, let pass = passwordTextField.text{
 //code
  }

Comment: Tell me your condition

Comment: i dont understand how you did it. i did it like.'                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "registertologin", sender: self)
                }
                else {
                    print(error!)
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error Creating Account ", message: "\(error!.localizedDescription)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }'

Comment: better look [http://prntscr.com/g1b15y]

Comment: when i do that i get an error saying "Use of unresolved identifier 'error'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Swift 3X...**

> Please change this line

```
if let email = emailTextField.text, let pass = passwordTextField.text, let name = namec?.capitalized{
 //code
  }
```

> in this line ...

```
 if let email = emailTextField.text, let pass = passwordTextField.text, let name = (namec?.capitalized.isEmpty)! ? nil:namec{{
 //code
  }
```